# How to generate per-package package-lock.json for existing Lerna mono-repo

Tags: npm, lerna, monorepo, package-lock.json

We have an existing [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) mono-repo that has a structure like:

```
/
  /packages
    /package1
    /package2
    /package3
    ...
```

We currently use Yarn for our project, and actually only have a top-level `yarn.lock` file, with no per-package `yarn.lock` since we never used Workspaces.

We are trying to switch to npm, and would like to generate a `package-lock.json` file for every package in the mono-repo, not just the top-level. How can we do this? Running `npm run lerna bootstrap --hoist` creates a top-level lock file, but does not include any `"dev": true` tags and doesn't include any local packages. The best I've been able to do is to do `npm run lerna add somePackage --scope=package1`, which even though `somePackage` already exists in `package`, causes a `package-lock.json` file to be generated for every package in the mono repo except `package1`. Further, the generated `package-lock.json` files do not have any dev dependencies.

Further, I can't go into each package and run `npm install` because `npm` doesn't know about many of the local packages we have in the mono-repo that other local packages depend on. Strange enough, even in the `package-lock.json` files generated from npm via the `lerna add`, those files don't include any references to local packages, only external ones.

So: how to I generate a `package-lock.json` file for every package in the mono-repo that also includes devDependencies?

Comment: Github thread - https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1462